# How to bring an application to front based on some condition (OS X) with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find a way to automate bringing a web browser to the front (ie - give it focus, make it visible on the screen) based on an event that happens in a web page.  I have full control over the webpage, so I can make it do whatever I need to in order to trigger this.

I need to have several apps open with a web page in the background which is monitoring some video cameras.  When a video camera has motion, I need the web browser window to come to the front so it's visible instead of whatever app was being used.

I was thinking something similar to what this guy was trying to do : [How to bring application to front every 15 minutes on Mac OS X Lion?](https://superuser.com/questions/349172/how-to-bring-application-to-front-every-15-minutes-on-mac-os-x-lion)

I was thinking of using AppleScript to run in a continuous loop, and once a second check the open page in Safari, scan for some change and then send "activate" command to Safari to bring it to the front.  Is this how I should go about this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just use launchd or cron instead of running the script as a background process.

1. Save a script like this somewhere in AppleScript Editor:

   ```
   try
       tell application "Safari"
           tell document 1 where name starts with "Webcam" to do JavaScript "--"
           if result is "--" then activate
       end tell
   end
   ```
2. Save a property list like this `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.superuser.443513.plist`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>com.superuser.443513</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>osascript</string>
           <string>/Users/username/Library/Scripts/script.scpt</string>
       </array>
       <key>StartInterval</key>
       <integer>5</integer> <!-- every 5 seconds -->
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.superuser.443513.plist`

---

Could you just use curl to check the condition? You could run it every other minute by editing the crontab with `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and adding a line like this:

`*/2 * * * * [[ -n "$(curl -L http://superuser.com/questions/443513 | grep automate)" ]] && open http://example.com`