# Mac lsof command find all processes for all users

Tags: macos, terminal.app, lsof

A while ago my teacher asked me to create a script that would kill Minecraft anytime it came up. It worked when the user themselves ran it, but it didn't if it was at root level.

Is there a command similar to `lsof` that found all processes, not just ones by the user that called lsof? I read the man page, but I'm not quite understanding it. Is there a `lsof` command that will get every single process, not just the users'?

This is the script, designed only for Macs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from time import sleep

while True:
    os.system("lsof | grep minecraft | cut -c 11-16 >mine.txt")
    f=open("mine.txt")
    l = f.readline()
    if len(l) > 0:
        os.system("kill "+l)
    f.close()
    os.system("echo > mine.txt")
    sleep(15)
```

Comment: Hey could I get my hands on that script? I could use it. I'd also like to expand it's capabilities so source code would be nice.

Comment: @Griffin Sure I'll edit into the question. It's fairly simple.

Comment: Actually that's an even better idea. Showing them the source might give them a better understand of what to change. Sadly I can not help because I'd don't know but other who do might find it useful.

Comment: why are you using `lsof`? it's designed to list open files. i think it'd be better to use something like `ps`. and as for listing the processes of all the users... if memory serves, that's impossible, as it's a potential security issue

Comment: :( Me no know python. How you do in C++

Comment: I know a little ANSII C but not C++ I'll figure it out real quick then I'll get back to you, but unless the user themselves activates the code it's useless at this point.

Comment: So I couldn't find a way of making terminal execute commands from c++, but if you could, and it sends the command lsof | grep minecraft | cut -c 11-16 >mine.txt then it reads from mine.txt and gets the first line, which is the pid, it then kills that pid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints the names of all processes:

```
ps -axco comm | sed 1d
```

- `-a`: all users (like root when run as user and user when run as root)
- `-x`: include processes without a controlling terminal
- `-o comm`: output only the command column
- `-c`: use command names instead of paths in the command column
- `sed 1d`: delete the first line (`COMM`)

If you only want to quit Minecraft, you could run a shell script like this (or just `killall minecraft` with [launchd or cron](https://superuser.com/questions/349172/how-to-bring-application-to-front-every-15-minutes-on-mac-os-x-lion/349174#349174)):

```
while sleep 5; do killall minecraft 2> /dev/null; done
```

Answer (score 1):

> a command similar to `lsof` that scan all processes, not just ones by the user that called `lsof`

```
pgrep -f minecraft
```

<sup>Where `minecraft` is the process to find. The command returns list of PIDs.</sup>

Here is the kill command (shell syntax):

```
kill $(pgrep -f minecraft)
```

Instead of using Python, here is a simple shell command to achieve the same:

```
while true; do echo kill $(pgrep -f minecraft) 2> /dev/null; sleep 15; done
```